# AddToRoleAsync is throwing strange SQL error

Tags: sql-server-2012, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3, asp.net-core-identity

In my ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1 app, the `AddToRoleAsync` call in the last line of the following code is throwing the **error**: `The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.` This is kind of odd since I don't have any other transaction running on SQL Server or anywhere else. I'm aware of this T-SQL error in general. But I'm not clear why the `AddToRoleAsync` call below is throwing this error. Please note the following code did successfully create a user before it threw the error in the next line of code.

```
List<String> usersList = GetAllUsers();

foreach (string s in usersList)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = s, UserRole = "TestRole" };
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "testpassword");

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
       var result_1 = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "TestRole");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same thing. What's interesting is I'm only getting this error on my Azure deployment - I get no error in my local dev environment.

Comment: @ih303 If I recall correctly after closing and restarting the project it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft changed the structure of `[AspNetRoles]` and others when using .Net Core apps. Now when you adding a new role statement to the `[AspNetRoles]`, you should declare the Role `NormalizedName` as well. 
**For instance:**

```
var role = "Manager";

var newRole = new IdentityRole()
{
    Name = role,
    NormalizedName = role.ToUpper() // Mandatory.
};

//! Adding the new Role into database and saving
await _apiDbContext.Roles.AddAsync(newRole);
await _apiDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Setting the **NormalizedName** role variable to upper-case, will let you using: `AddToRoleAsync` without any strange errs.

```
var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email);
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(currentUser, "Manager");
```

> _userManager belongs to **`UserManager<YourIdentityUser>`**